# Error No overload method for 'Add' takes '0' arguments, using Word Interop

Tags: c#, office-interop

here is my code.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    {
        // first we are creating application of word.
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application WordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
        // now creating new document.
        WordApp.Documents.Add();
        // see word file behind your program
        WordApp.Visible = true;
        // get the reference of active document
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc = WordApp.ActiveDocument;
        // set openfiledialog to select multiple image files
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        ofd.Filter = "Images (*.BMP;*.JPG;*.GIF)|*.BMP;*.JPG;*.GIF";
        ofd.Title = "Select Image To Insert....";
        ofd.Multiselect = true;
        // if user select OK, then process for adding images
        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            // iterating process for adding all images which is selected by filedialog
            foreach (string filename in ofd.FileNames)
            {
                // now add the picture in active document reference
                doc.InlineShapes.AddPicture(filename, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
            }
        }
        // file is saved.
        doc.SaveAs("c:\\hello.doc", Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
        // application is now quit.
        WordApp.Quit(Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
    }

}
```

I am facing below mentioned error at `WordApp.Documents.Add();`

> Error: No overload method for Add takes 0 arguments

Can you pls help me in resolving this error?

I am new to coding.

Comment: You need to pass a object to `Add` 

Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.documents.add.ASPX

Comment: Please some research effort first before posting: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: Funny, but the documentation says that each of the parameters is "optional". Ugly how they could not make this work cleanly in C# as real optional parameters.

Comment: which version of .Net framework you are using ?

Comment: If I recall correctly, you should be able to omit those parameters if you're using C# 4+

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is a version issue,  you are passing `Type.Missing` to *optional* parameters in other methods.Then you should pass  `Type.Missing` to the parameters of `Add` method as well.

```
WordApp.Documents.Add(Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
```

Comment: I think he uses C#3.0 (or less), so there are no optional parameters

Answer (score 0):

```
object objTest = new object();
objTest = Type.Missing;
WordApp.Documents.Add(ref objTest, ref objTest, ref objTest, ref objTest);
```